# Conditions on eloquent query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I need to show the marks of all the students of a course using Laravel 5.4, so i've made a table like this;
In the controller:

```
$courses    = Courses::find($id);
$marks      = Marks::where([
                            ['course_id','=',$id]
                            ])->orderBy('id','asc')->get();
return view('courses.show', compact('courses','marks'));
```

In the view:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
   <thead class="text-center">
      <th class="text-center">
          <b>Alumno</b>
      </th>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="text-left">
        @foreach($courses->tests-> as $t)
        <tr>
           <td>
               <b>{{ $t->info->apaterno }} {{ $t->info->amaterno }}, {{ $t->info->name }}</b>
           </td>
           @foreach($courses->number->pupil as $m)
           <td>
              Nota {{ $m->mark }}
           </td>
           @endforeach
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

So, my question is the following. How can i make as `<th>` as test are, and then list so many `<td>` are, with the condition that every mark belongs to a pupil.

Comment: What is your relationship defined in model?

Comment: courses belongsTo school //// courses belongsTo number //// courses belongs to professor //// courses hasMany tests

Comment: And the other model, Marks, has the following relationships: marks belongsTo school // marks belongsTo courses // marks belongsTo pupil //marks belongsTo tests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works when you have relationship, suppose in `Courses` model you have relationship something like this:

```
public function marks()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Marks');
}
```

Then you can use `eager loading` something like this:

```
$courses    = Courses::find($id)->with('marks');
```

This will give you course with marks associated with them, moreover it is more efficient.

For more information you can see documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, in fact i'm using eager loading. But my problem is related with the loops, and how to relation the mark with the student id to show it on a determinate `<td>`

Comment: Are you looking for the counts, just to loop that number of `<th>`?

Comment: Well I got your point. But I think each test might have different name?

Comment: In the marks model each mark is referenced by an id, course_id and test_id

Comment: And in the tests model, each test has an id and name.

Comment: Then it better to take `test` as base model and use with statement for other relation which you want to call.